# issue changing properties on project items using multi-project vstemplate with IWizard

Tags: vsix

I am creating a VSIX extension that generates a multi-project solution to be distributed. I would like to do several things to individual items I include in each projects vstemplate but think I may be taking the wrong approach. I have created a IWizard and am able to debug the solution. I added a custom item type to the project items in vstemplate in order to identify which ones I want to flag. I am then doing the following to change a ProjectItems Build Action from Content to Compile. I am still learning Visual Studio Extensability and have very limited experience using the objects so I apologize if the below is horrendous!

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
{
    var myproject = (VSProject)project.Object;
    foreach (ProjectItem pi in myproject.ProjectItems)
    {
        var myBuildAction = pi.Properties.Item("ItemType").Value;
        if  myBuildAction == "CompileContent")
            pi.Properties.Item("ItemType").Value = "Compile";
    }
}
```

This is my item in vstemplate

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Project" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate-sdkextension/2010">
<ProjectItem TargetFileName="MyFolder\$ext_safeprojectname$\$ext_safeprojectname$_CodeFile.cs" ReplaceParameters="true" ItemType="CompileContent">CodeFile.cs</ProjectItem>
```

Comment: You've neglected to mention what, specifically, is not working ;-)

Comment: @Cameron Sorry, lol. I get an exception when looking up 'pi.Properties.Item("ItemType").Value'.

Comment: I would recommend using the RunFinished override instead and iterate on the the solution templates.
Problably you have one project item that does not have the ItemType property. So you need to wrap the call to handle that case, like this example:
EnvDTE.Property property = projectItem.Properties.Item("BuildAction");
if (property != null)
{
 return (VSLangProj.prjBuildAction)property.Value;
}